# Laravel Error: what does this mean?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4.2

I have an internal site that is not accessible outside of my work and I found this error in my logs with a timestamp where noone should be accessing the site. 
I can read that something is up with the router but I don't know enough about the internal workings to know what is wrong...also I have a related issue where my site is compromised and writing php files everywehere. I am trying to determine if this is related but I don't know what it means.

```
[2016-12-05 00:39:43] staging.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException' in /var/www/html/mysite/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php:148
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/mysite/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(1054): Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection->match(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#1 /var/www/html/mysite/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(1022): Illuminate\Routing\Router->findRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#2 /var/www/html/mysite/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(1001): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#3 /var/www/html/mysite/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(781): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#4 /var/www/html/mysite/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(745): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#5 /var/www/html/mysite/vendor/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar/src/Middleware/Stack.php(34): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#6 /var/www/html/mysite/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware.php(72): Barryvdh\Debugbar\Middleware\Stack->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#7 /var/www/html/mysite/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Queue.php(47): Illuminate\Session\Middleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#8 /var/www/html/mysite/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Guard.php(51): Illuminate\Cookie\Queue->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#9 /var/www/html/mysite/vendor/stack/builder/src/Stack/StackedHttpKernel.php(23): Illuminate\Cookie\Guard->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#10 /var/www/html/mysite/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(641): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#11 /var/www/html/mysite/public/index.php(49): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->run()
#12 /var/www/html/mysite/server.php(19): require_once('/var/www/html/t...')
```

Comment: Some `non-existent` route/URI has been requested and laravel just made a log entry.

Comment: This looks like a 404 error. The page or URL requested is not found

Comment: Any idea what would make a request at such an odd hour? I'm sure nobody is working at that time.

Comment: There is no way of telling, the only thing you can really do is setup some error handler which catches that exception, logs it, and also logs the requested URL which was hit and whatever other information you think would be useful, user agent, logged in user, ip address, etc...  That way when it happens again, you at least have some context.

Comment: Its stack trace of 404, most likely your site was visited by robot, this is not a real question and it should be deleted.

Comment: @Kyslik How does a robot visit a restricted internal site? Read the first 5 words in the Question.

Comment: I have read the question fully. I don't know your setup; your best options is to check access log from apache https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html#accesslog you will see IP and time so match it with this stack-trace.

Comment: @Kyslik Thanks for your help. No access log entry at the time of the error.